# Casting a list of an unknown type to a generic list type

Tags: c#, list, casting

I'm processing a lot of FieldInfo information and I want to add exceptions for certain types of data to process them differently (To make a neat output string) but I can't find a way to cast the object to a List so I can get the count from it.

My code:

```
string str = "";
string value = "";

foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in fieldInfos)
{
    if (fieldInfo.Name == "Sprite" || fieldInfo.Name == "Background")
    {
        value = "Unreadable";
    }
    else if (fieldInfo.GetValue(type) == null)
    {
        value = "Null";
    }
    else
    {
        switch (fieldInfo.GetValue(type).GetType().Name)
        {
            default:
                value = fieldInfo.GetValue(type).ToString();
                break;
            case "Color":
                value = ((Color)fieldInfo.GetValue(type)).Name;
                break;
            case "List`1":
                value = (((System.Collections.Generic.List<>)fieldInfo.GetValue(type)).Count - 1).ToString();
                break;
        }
    }

    str += "        " + fieldInfo.Name + ": " + value + Environment.NewLine;
}
return str;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast it to non-generic `ICollection` instead:

```
(((System.Collections.ICollection)fieldInfo.GetValue(type)).Count - 1).ToString();
```

It will give you access to `Count` property.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I will accept your answer when I can!

Comment: @user1763295 If it worked.. Why can't you accept it as answer now?

Comment: @ElectricRouge You have to wait 15 minutes after question is posted to accept an answer.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek oh I did knew about that restriction

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

If you're just after the number of items then just use the non-generic `IList` which `List<>` also implements:

```
case "List`1":
  value = (((System.Collections.IList)fieldInfo.GetValue(type)).Count - 1).ToString();
  break;
```

You could add some flexibility by supporting any container by changing the `default` clause to this:

```
default:
 if (typeof(System.Collections.ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(fieldInfo.GetValue(type).GetType())
   value = (((System.Collections.ICollection)fieldInfo.GetValue(type)).Count - 1).ToString();
  else
    value = fieldInfo.GetValue(type).ToString();
  break;
```

Now you'll handle collections such as `Dictionary<>` and `LinkedList<>` as well as `List<>`

Comment: You meant `IList`, didn't you?